# Is there a better way to do a regular expression search and delete in Emacs?

Tags: regex, search, emacs, replace

In reading the emacs help and emacs wiki I haven't found an obvious way to search for a regular expression and then simply delete all the matching text it finds.   I originally thought I could use the regular expression search and replace feature `M-x query-replace-regexp`, but could not figure out how to replace my matches with an empty string.  Hitting return on an empty string would simply exit. The field highlighted by the incremental reg expr search (C-M-s) doesn't obey the same rules as a marked block of text.  Otherwise I would simply cut it (C-w).

Consider the following scenario.  I wanted to strip the trailing zeros from a list of numbers that have 3 or more zeros.

```
0.075000
0.050000
0.10000
0.075000
```

So this is the round about way I solved it.

```
F3                - begin keyboard macro
C-M-s for 000*    - forward regexpr search
                    match the trailing zeros find the first match
C-<SPC>           - mark the position at the end of the match (after the last 0)
C-M-r for [1-9]   - reverse regexpr search
                    match the reverse non-zero digit, mark is now on the non-zero digit
C-f               - move mark forward one space
C-w               - cut/kill the text
F4                - end keyboard macro, run until list is processed
```

Surely there is a better way to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: May not be what you want but I use emacs with [evil-mode](https://gitorious.org/evil/pages/Home) which gives me glorious vim bindings. with that (and in vim) you can do `:%s/my_regex_to_match//g`

Comment: @MikeH-R sneaky VI people.  smh

Comment: @Anycorn I know! one day someone dropped some vim in my emacs and I haven't been able to get it out since then :)

Comment: @MikeH-R I just `alias vi=emacs` on unsuspecting coworkers

Comment: @Anycorn wow, that is evil genius work!

Comment: My concern is that you did not find `regexp-replace` or `query-replace-regexp` yourself by asking Emacs.  I assume you looked for how to do this in the Emacs manual and somehow didn't come across those.  How were you looking?  Did you try `i replace TAB`, for example?  Maybe something more needs to be added to the index of the manual.

Comment: It's peculiar that you can use macros but haven't found `query-replace-regexp`.  You can also combine isearch-regexp with query-replace-regexp by calling the latter straight from the former, i.e. <kbd>C-M-%</kbd>

Comment: Yeah at least when I try it `M-x query-replace-regexp <RET> 000+ <RET> <RET>` simply exits without doing blank replacements.  That was the non-obvious piece for me.  I think I got stuck looking at the query-replace-regexp help.  After hearing folks suggestions I now find `M-x replace-regexp` help which does do an empty replace.  Thanks all.

Comment: Edited my original post to make it more clear that I was stuck on `M-x query-replace-regexp`

Comment: `query-replace-regexp` absolutely lets you replace with an empty string! Verify with `emacs -Q` to disable any customisations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [replace-regexp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html) to do that. To strip trailing 0's from numbers that have 3 or more 0s:

```
M-x replace-regexp <RET>000+<RET><RET>
```

Comment: rather 000+ taking three or more zero

Comment: Well pointed out @AndreasRöhler. I wasn't paying attention. fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Mike H-R and all who responded.  This solution seems the simplest to me. In my emacs notes I also indicated that highlighting may be a good idea since this replaces all occurrences.  `M-x highlight-regexp <RET> 000+ <RET> <RET>` then
`M-x replace-regexp <RET> (default 000+ ->): <RET>`

Comment: To strip trailing zeros incrementally: `M-x query-replace-regexp <RET> 000+ <RET> <SPC>` not `<RET> <RET>` I am a victim of my own myopia.  =)

Answer (score 1):

Like `replace-regexp`?

```
M-x replace-regexp
Replace regexp: $.*foo
Replace regexp $.*foo with:
```

You can even make your own function, eg `kill-regexp`

In your scratch buffer (or some other buffer) write

```
(defun kill-regexp (regexp)
  (interactive "sRegular expression to kill: ")
  (replace-regexp regexp "")
)
```

Make sure the cursor is somewhere on the function and then evaluate the defun:

```
`M-x eval-defun`
```

`(interactive ...)` means you can call it interactively.  Leading `s` means the `regexp` argument is a string.  Text following it is what will be displayed at the prompt (minibuffer)

Comment: good call on the `kill-regexp` function. put it into your .emacs file to have it loaded every time you start.